# How to allocate memory for template-classes, that are passed between different modules by shared pointers

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, shared-ptr, allocation

I have a very specific problem as part of a much bigger project. The project consists of an executable along with different dll's, some of them dynamically loaded/unloaded at runtime. I have full access to all sub-projects, but the basic structure of the classes needs to be like this:

One of the libraries provides a templated class, which inherits from a non-templated class, like this:

```
//lets call this object.dll
//its of course splitted into cpp/h files

class Object{};

template<typename T>
class TemplateObject : public Object{};

//whether i inherit here or just use a member does not change the problem...
class SharedObject : public std::shared_ptr<Object>{};

template<typename T>
SharedObject create(T& o){
  return SharedObject{new TemplateObject<T>{o}};
};
```

Constructors are properly implemented to make these things work. The basic idea behind it is this:

- `TemplatedObject` is a class that manages access to some type T, in my case this is a function pointer.
- `Object` is the common base class, providing me (limited) access to the functionality of `TemplatedObject`.
- both `TemplatedObject` and `Object` should not be copied, moved or in any other way be messed around with and therefore be hidden to users of this dll. Even if its not the case yet, their copy/move-assignment/constructors will probably be deleted or private.
- instead, a `SharedObject` might be passed to other dll's and the executable, providing only the needed access.
- to create these Objects, theres a (templated) factory-function `create`. This function is called from different modules (dll's and executable).

This is working fine, as long as the last shared_ptr is always destructed in the same model as the first one to an object was created. If not, i get an access violation. I am sure my problem is caused by the fact, that memory is allocated in one module and deallocated in another module (see other questions for that). object.dll is not dynamically loaded/unloaded, so im totally fine if all the created objects live inside the heap memory of object.dll.

What i tried to do is this: I overloaded the operator new/delete like this for both `Object` and `TemplateObject`

```
static void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
  return allocate(sz);
}
static void* operator new[](std::size_t sz)
{
  return allocate(sz);
}
static void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
  deallocate(ptr, sz);
}
static void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
  deallocate(ptr,sz);
}
```

And defined two global (non-template) functions inside object.dll

```
void* allocate(std::size_t sz)
{
  return ::operator new(sz);
}
void deallocate(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
  ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

Since i work under windows, i have marked those two functions with declspec(dllimport/export)

I could verify via debug-output that the operators of TemplateObject and global-functions are actually called, but i still get an access-violation error when i keep a shared_ptr in a different module than the original one.

This leads me tho the conclusion, that i either

- have forgotten to implement some specific version of delete (or maybe new)

or

- need to implement my own allocator to use with the shared_ptrs, which at least calls the allocation-functions inside object.dll, but i have no clue how to do this. Can i derive from std::allocator? And then just overwrite a special function (i guess allocate()/deallocate()) ? Or do i need to implement a whole new one?

I guess it would work if my `create()` would not have to be templated, but in this case im glad for any help how to solve the problem or where to find a good introduction into custom allocators.

### Edit

I stepped through the process of resetting the shared pointer inside a wrong module and found the access violation to be thrown in this line inside `<memory>`:

```
void _Decref()
    {   // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Mtx, _Uses) == 0)
        {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
-->     _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
        }
    }
```

This looks like my custom delete-operator is never called.
I also tried it with a Deleter-class as SergeyA proposed in the comments - same Error, same line.

Comment: Why not use a custom deleter for your shared_ptr?

Comment: I've tried using a Deleter like this: 
`template <typename T>
class Deleter {
public:
 void operator()(TemplatedObject<T>* ptr) {
  deallocate(ptr, sizeof(*ptr));
 }
};` but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but it seems like you're building your dlls and exe with private msvcrt (/MT), while you should use shared (/MD).
Every instance of msvcrt has it's own heap, FILE objects, and whatever else the standard library is managing so deleting using another instance is like calling free on a wild pointer.

Comment: It is actually set to Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd). What i am trying to achieve is, that all of the objects live inside the heap of object.dll, regardless of where the actual call to create() happens or where the last shared_ptr is destructed. Thats why i redefined operator new/delete to use a function for allocating that lives inside the dll.